# Spring type=Not Found, status=404 No message available

Tags: java, spring, maven

The only thing I have done so far is create a package called "controller" with a "HomeController.java" file inside it, with this code:

```
    package com.demo.spring.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String index(){

            return "Hello World.";
        }
    }
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My file structure:
[image]

Full error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Jan 17 15:17:56 GMT 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Comment: Try to use this with method @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody

Comment: That makes no difference

Comment: use @RestController instead of Controller and then you don't need  ResponseBody...

Comment: @RestController will automatically convert the response to json

Comment: I have ResponseBody. I'd like to fix it using Controller if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a file missing called DemoSpringApplication.java. It should have been in com.demo.spring package.

This file should have been a default file. I'm not sure if I accidentally removed it or if it was never there. I created a new project inside IntelliJ and it showed in the new project automatically.

See this image compared to the above:
[image]

Comment: So if you didnt have this file how did you start the application?

Answer (score 3):

If you're returning a raw string like this you should add the @ResponseBody annotation below your other annotation.

Alternatively, you can leave that off and do it like this.  This says you're returning a valid HTTP response entity (200 code) with a string, and it will be converted into JSON automatically for you.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "whatever_path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getResult() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated question. I added @ResponseBody after pasting this code into question.

Comment: I am following a tutorial which uses ResponseBody, I would like to continue using this. However I did try your code and gave me a "cannot resolve symbol" error on ResponseEntity and HttpStatus.

Comment: Sounds like you just didn't add the import statement at the top of your code?  import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;  I'm confident it's included in your spring POM inclusions already.

Comment: You were correct with that import statement missing, and I also added one for HttpStatus however even with this I still receive the same error.

Comment: Maybe maven clean install to refresh your POM dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I received such error when 'SpringApplication' class and controller classes are in  different packages.

Adding

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "a.b.c")`

fixed my issue